# Getting XML in HTTP Response and reading it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml

I have the following method, I have one more method through which I am calling this method, but have no luck yet.

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"isphone-config"]) {
            Pusername = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"authentication_username"];    
            Ppassword = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"authentication_password"];
            Pidentity = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"sip_identity"];
            Pdomain   = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"domain"];
            Pprotocol = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"protocol"];
            Pudpport  = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"registrar_port"];
            Ptcpport  = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"listening_port"];

            NSLog(@"Title: %@, ID: %@", Pusername, Ppassword);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am calling it from the following method..

```
NSString* username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username_preference"];
NSString* accountPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password_preference"];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@test.com/test.php",username,accountPassword];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: response];

NSLog(@"at parser %@", parser);

[parser setDelegate:self];
```

I am having issues in the last line of the code from where I am calling parser. I assume that this line will call the method parser, correct me if I am wrong. I don't know which files, interfaces and classes I have to import, include or implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML parsing with NSXMLParser is much more difficult, check Apple's example "earthquakes".

Instead I suggest you to use another XML parser. For example, [this one](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument):

[Also, good article about how to choose parser.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Comment: This approach is far easy than NSXMLParser... I spent a lot of time on NSXMLParser and had no luck !!!